# How can I efficiently sort two large numpy arrays into an array of arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Assume I have two 2-dimensional numpy arrays which are each actually very large (order 1million elements):

```
a = np.array([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
b = np.array([11,22,33],[44,55,66],[77,88,99])
```

I would like to create a new array whose elements are 1d, two-element arrays from the i,j component of a and the i,j component of b:

```
c = [[1,11], [2,22], [3,33], [4,44], [5,55], [6,66], [7,77], [8,88], [9,99]]
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
c = np.array([])
for i in range(0,3):
     for j in range(0,3):
          number_pair = numpy.array([a[i,j], b[i,j]])
          c = numpy.append(c, number_pair)
```

However this 'flattens' the array producing:

```
c = [1,11,2,22,3,33,4,44,5,55,6,66,7,77,8,88,9,99]
```

Is this something vstack could handle? Is there a much easier way to think about this and still get the desired result?

If anyone could give a toy example I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How about `np.stack([a, b], -1).reshape(-1,2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with something simpler - `zip` on simple arrays:

```
In [113]: a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
     ...: b = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]                                                     
In [114]: list(zip(a,b))                                                                       
Out[114]: 
[(1, 11),
 (2, 22),
 (3, 33),
 (4, 44),
 (5, 55),
 (6, 66),
 (7, 77),
 (8, 88),
 (9, 99)]
```

That's what you want - except it's a list of tuples, not lists.

Your `a` and `b` appear to have some sort of nesting, lists with a list.  SO they need to be flattened to use this kind of `zip`.  There are ways of flattening lists, but it's simpler to use arrays.

But first - try your `a` expression:

```
In [116]: a = np.array([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-41a87620921a> in <module>
----> 1 a = np.array([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])

ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted
```

You are missing brackets:

```
In [117]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])                                              
In [118]: a                                                                                    
Out[118]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [119]: a.shape                                                                              
Out[119]: (3, 3)
In [120]: b = np.array([[11,22,33],[44,55,66],[77,88,99]])                                     
In [121]: b.shape                                                                              
Out[121]: (3, 3)
```

Flattening an array is easy:

```
In [122]: a.ravel()                                                                            
Out[122]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [123]: list(zip(a.ravel(), b.ravel()))                                                      
Out[123]: 
[(1, 11),
 (2, 22),
 (3, 33),
 (4, 44),
 (5, 55),
 (6, 66),
 (7, 77),
 (8, 88),
 (9, 99)]
```

We could also join those two flatten arrays into one:

```
In [125]: np.array([a.ravel(),b.ravel()])                                                      
Out[125]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]])
```

and then use `numpy` transpose:

```
In [126]: np.array([a.ravel(),b.ravel()]).T                                                    
Out[126]: 
array([[ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 22],
       [ 3, 33],
       [ 4, 44],
       [ 5, 55],
       [ 6, 66],
       [ 7, 77],
       [ 8, 88],
       [ 9, 99]])
```

There are number of other ways of combining these arrays.

```
In [127]: np.array((a,b))                                                                      
Out[127]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[11, 22, 33],
        [44, 55, 66],
        [77, 88, 99]]])
In [128]: _.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,2)                                                     
Out[128]: 
array([[ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 22],
       [ 3, 33],
       [ 4, 44],
       [ 5, 55],
       [ 6, 66],
       [ 7, 77],
       [ 8, 88],
       [ 9, 99]])
```